# How to make a join table using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following two entities/models:

```
public class Achievement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
}
```

How to make a join table in Entity Framework Core using the two entities above? Is what I'm doing suffiecient for Entity Framework Core to know the relation and make a join table for it?

I have Many-To-Many relation and I want Entity Framework Core to create a join table like:

```
public class UserAchievement 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AchievementId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to Join ? You have setup your Data-Model ? It's a Many-To-Many Relation ?
Than you just need to Access the users of Achievement or the Achievements of User, and you have your joined data. There is no Join-statement needed.

Comment: Oh this you call a 'join-table'. Well you don't have to do anything, if you have setup your relation. Is your question how to setup a Many-To-Many relation ? https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research and found that for now there is currently no conventional way to let Entity Framework Core automatically create a join entity for many-to-many relationships, however [in the future this might possible](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368).

For now we have to create our own join entity and configure it using Fluent API.

The join entity:

```
public class UserAchievement 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int AchievementId { get; set; }
    public Achievement Achievement { get; set; }
}
```

Other entities:

```
public class Achievement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAchievement> UserAchievements { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAchievement> UserAchievements { get; set; }
}
```

and then configure it using Fluent API in DbContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAchievement>().HasKey(ua => new { ua.UserId, ua.AchievementId });
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAchievement> UserAchievements { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The above is correct and has been validated with DotNet 3 and above. This was specifically tested on DotNet 5.